# Is it possible to make y the subject of this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{ty+3t-y-3}{ty-2t+4y-8}$$
$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t(y+3)-(y+3)}{t(y-2)+4(y-2)}$$
$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{(y+3)(t-1)}{(y-2)(t+4)}$$
$$\therefore \frac{y-2}{y+3}dy=\frac{t-1}{t+4}dt$$
$$\therefore \bigg(\frac{-5}{y+3}+1\bigg)dy=\bigg(\frac{-5}{t+4}+1\bigg)dt$$
$$\therefore -5\int\frac{1}{y+3}dy+\int1dy=-5\int\frac{1}{t+4}dt+\int1dt$$
$$\therefore -5\ln{|y+3|}+y=-5\ln{|t+4|}+t+C_1$$
$$\therefore 5\big(\ln{|y+3|}-\ln{|t+4|}\big)=y-t+C_2,\:\:\:C_2=-C_1$$
$$\therefore 5\bigg(\ln{\frac{|y+3|}{|t+4|}}\bigg)=y-t+C_2$$

Here I'm stuck. I can't see any more useful manipulations to do to get $y$ isolated in order to give the answer with $y$ as subject of the solution equation.

What keywords should I look for? What strategy should I try?

Comment: There is nothing much further to do. One can try to give an explicit formula using the Lambert-W function.

Comment: Using ProductLog:  $$y(t) = -5 W\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{(t+4)^5 \left(-e^{-c_1-t}\right)}}{5 e^{3/5}}\right)-3$$ (Lambert's W function)

Comment: The substitutions $z = y+3, s = t+4$ make it obvious that $z = s$, or $y = t+1$ is *a* solution. However the general solution is still not nice.